# Settings Application Implementation - boolean values set to "no" by default

Tags: iphone, settings, ios4, nsuserdefaults

The question, by itself, implies that the `DefaultValue` property in my `Root.plist` file was set to "no".  This is unfortunately not true.  To verify what my problem is, I am trying to use a section of the iPhone's Settings application.  I am using this to show/hide certain on-screen items.  By default, the "shown" property was set to "on."  Unfortunately, all of the on-screen items were hidden before the user went to the settings app, turned the options off, then turned them on again!  Here is my code.

```
if ([prefs boolForKey:@"artwork_prefrence"] == YES)
        currentArtwork.hidden = NO;
    else if ([prefs boolForKey:@"artwork_prefrence"] == NO)
        currentArtwork.hidden = YES;

    if ([prefs boolForKey:@"title_prefrence"] == YES)
        currentSong.hidden = NO;
    else if ([prefs boolForKey:@"title_prefrence"] == NO)
        currentSong.hidden = YES;

    if ([prefs boolForKey:@"artist_prefrence"] == YES)
        currentArtist.hidden = NO;
    else if ([prefs boolForKey:@"artist_prefrence"] == NO)
        currentArtist.hidden = YES;

    if ([prefs boolForKey:@"next_prefrence"] == YES)
        nextbutton.hidden = NO;
    else if ([prefs boolForKey:@"next_prefrence"] == NO)
        nextbutton.hidden = YES;

    if ([prefs boolForKey:@"prev_prefrence"] == YES)
        prevbutton.hidden = NO;
    else if ([prefs boolForKey:@"prev_prefrence"] == NO)
        prevbutton.hidden = YES;

    if ([prefs boolForKey:@"progress_prefrence"] == YES)
        progressslider.hidden = NO;
    else if ([prefs boolForKey:@"progress_prefrence"] == NO)
        progressslider.hidden = YES;
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *registerDefaults* in your initialize-method in your App Delegate.